# How to create a power function

Tags: python

I was wondering if any of you knew how to create a function calculating powers of two when passing lists inside the function and returning a list:

For example

```
>>mypowerfunction([2,4,..]
>>[4,16,..]
```

I can get it to work but not returning a list, it always returns single ints when I try doing it...

Comment: Show us your attempt(s).

Comment: What does your "mypowerfunction" contains?

Comment: also a nice time to use map and lambda: import math; power_funct = lambda x: math.pow(x,2); map(power_funct,[2,3,4,5,6]); # The output is [4.0, 9.0, 16.0, 25.0, 36.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perfect time for you to learn about [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> def mypowerfunction(my_list, exponent=2):
...     return [x ** exponent for x in my_list]
... 
>>> mypowerfunction([2,4,3])
[4, 16, 9]
```

Comment: great thanks, what I was doing earlier was: for x in args x*x print(x). do you know why the list prints ints in this case?

Comment: @user26450: I don't understand your confusion. Your code doesn't build a new list or change an existing one. You just print (and ask us why it prints).

Comment: this is the same result using return: def mypowerfunction(args):    **newline*** for x in args:    ***newline*** x = x*x     ***newline**** print(x) ***newline*** print(mypowerfunction([4,5]))     **newline*** now this will only print 25 and I was wondering why this was the case so that I wont make this mistake again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well if you meant powers-of-2, then:

```
def mypowerfunction(list):
    return [1<<i for i in list]
```

Or if you possibly meant squares, then:

```
def mypowerfunction(list):
    return [i*i for i in list]
```

Comment: The optimization of using a bit shift instead of multiplying by two is largely wasted here. Given that the person who is asking this is obviously a beginner programmer, I think a more straigh-forward solution would be better.

Comment: According to the first answer, that person is looking for a square function rather than a power-of-2 function...